# I cant export .obj with textures?

Tags: export

I'm trying to make a hat and every time I export it into .obj file there's no texture. any help? I'm using 3D builder to view it by the way!

Comment: You have to use a UV texture. Click U > Project cylinder or unwrap it and apply texture.

Comment: when i unmap it, it says that it has no uniform scale.

Comment: Ctrl + a > scale to apply the changes that you made on the scale in object mode. Then unwrap or uv project again

Comment: I did this and the texture still doesn't up. is there anything else i should do?

Comment: Try to create a cube, use UV smart unwrap, and to the UV assign a saved PNG image, then export the cube to obj (flags include UVs and write materials should be enabled); aside the .obj there should be a .mtl file with a line referring to the saved image like "map_Kd Untitled.png". Then reopen Blender, delete all, import the obj, and it should be textured.